# How to bring the values of some columns one row up while maintaing the other columns constant?

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe with monthly periods. It gathers reported revenues for several companies meaning that values are updated quarterly and the other months are just "NA". The problem is that some companies report in March/June/September/December and others in April/July/October/January.

My data frame looks like this:

```
datadate <-c(31012000,28022000,31032000,30042000,31052000,30062000,31072000,31082000,30092000,31102000,30112000,31122000,31012001)
AAPL <- c(NA,NA,100,NA,NA,120,NA,NA,110,NA,NA,135,NA)
MSFT <- c(NA,NA,55,NA,NA,70,NA,NA,65,NA,NA,60,NA)
GE <- c(NA,NA,NA,25,NA,NA,30,NA,NA,25,NA,NA,30)
PFE <- c(NA,NA,NA,20,NA,NA,15,NA,NA,25,NA,NA,30)
df <- data.frame (datadate,AAPL,MSFT,GE,PFE)
df$datadate <- strptime (df$datadate,format="%d%m%Y")
```

However, I would like for all values to appear in March/June/September/December as follows:

```
GE.new <- c(NA,NA,25,NA,NA,30,NA,NA,25,NA,NA,30,NA)
PFE.new <- c(NA,NA,20,NA,NA,15,NA,NA,25,NA,NA,30,NA)
df.new <- data.frame (datadate,AAPL,MSFT,GE.new,PFE.new)
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Your data

I had to change your dates with `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
df$datadate <- dmy(df$datadate)
```

#### alternative dplyr solution

```
# Find companies that report in April
Apr <- df %>%
         mutate(month = month(datadate)) %>%
         group_by(month) %>%
         filter(month == 4) %>%
         ungroup(month) %>%
         select(-month)

companies <- colnames(Apr[2:ncol(Apr)])[!is.na(Apr[1,2:ncol(Apr)])]
# "GE"  "PFE"
```

This is easier done by filtering for a single date but because you said that companies might cease to exist at a given year, I grouped data by month first. I also assumed some companies might start after 1960, which this should account for as well.

```
df1 <- df %>%
         mutate_at(vars(companies), funs(lead(.)))
```

#### Output

```
     datadate AAPL MSFT GE PFE
1  2000-01-31   NA   NA NA  NA
2  2000-02-28   NA   NA NA  NA 
3  2000-03-31  100   55 25  20
4  2000-04-30   NA   NA NA  NA
5  2000-05-31   NA   NA NA  NA
6  2000-06-30  120   70 30  15
7  2000-07-31   NA   NA NA  NA
8  2000-08-31   NA   NA NA  NA
9  2000-09-30  110   65 25  25
10 2000-10-31   NA   NA NA  NA
11 2000-11-30   NA   NA NA  NA
12 2000-12-31  135   60 30  30
13 2001-01-31   NA   NA NA  NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea via `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(grp = cumsum(c(1, diff(rowSums(is.na(.[-1])) == 4) != 0))) %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(-datadate), funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(-datadate), funs(replace(., duplicated(.)|all(. == 0), NA))) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 select(-grp)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 13 x 5
>      datadate  AAPL  MSFT    GE   PFE
>        <dttm> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
>  1 2000-01-31    NA    NA    NA    NA
>  2 2000-02-28    NA    NA    NA    NA
>  3 2000-03-31   100    55    25    20
>  4 2000-04-30    NA    NA    NA    NA
>  5 2000-05-31    NA    NA    NA    NA
>  6 2000-06-30   120    70    30    15
>  7 2000-07-31    NA    NA    NA    NA
>  8 2000-08-31    NA    NA    NA    NA
>  9 2000-09-30   110    65    25    25
> 10 2000-10-31    NA    NA    NA    NA
> 11 2000-11-30    NA    NA    NA    NA
> 12 2000-12-31   135    60    30    30
> 13 2001-01-31    NA    NA    NA    NA
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the same companies that always report a month later, you can simply choose to shift those companies' values forward by a month:

```
# preprocessing df as the POSIXlt format was throwing error for me
df$datadate <- as.POSIXct(df$datadate) 

df %>% mutate_at(vars(GE, PFE), lead, n = 1L)

     datadate AAPL MSFT GE PFE
1  2000-01-31   NA   NA NA  NA
2  2000-02-28   NA   NA NA  NA
3  2000-03-31  100   55 25  20
4  2000-04-30   NA   NA NA  NA
5  2000-05-31   NA   NA NA  NA
6  2000-06-30  120   70 30  15
7  2000-07-31   NA   NA NA  NA
8  2000-08-31   NA   NA NA  NA
9  2000-09-30  110   65 25  25
10 2000-10-31   NA   NA NA  NA
11 2000-11-30   NA   NA NA  NA
12 2000-12-31  135   60 30  30
13 2001-01-31   NA   NA NA  NA
```

Comment: It is always the same companies. But I have a data frame with more than 23000 companies and I don't know all of them. Also, I have data from 1960 to 2016 and some companies cease to exist in the meantime. So, unless I can somehow find the all the companies for each that is at least one value in April/July/October/January I cannot apply that. Do you know how to do it? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @MiguelLeiriaLagesDeCarvalh In that case I'd say Sotos' answer is more robust.